# scrollTop issue with ajax success error Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to achieve a smooth scroll after ajax content has been loaded i currently had the following code :

```
document.getElementById('dynamictabstrp').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
```

but smooth scrolling is only supported in mozilla firefox so i tried the below

```
   var siteUrl = "<?php echo  Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB); ?>";  
   //alert(siteUrl);
  var urlT = siteUrl+'getCust.php';
  jQuery.ajax({                    
  url: urlT,     
  type: 'post', // performing a POST request
  data : {  
  data2 : val   
  },
 //dataType: 'json',                   
 success: function(data)         
{
 if(jQuery( ".frequency" ).html(data)){
 jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('#2010').offset().top }, 'slow');
 //document.getElementById('dynamictabstrp').scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});
  }

}
```

and i get the following error Cannot read property 'top' of undefined any suggestions would be appreciated because i'm lost with it.

Comment: make sure you have  element with id `2010` in your document content

Comment: Turns out i didn't but now i have passed other elements in and now it gives me this error jQuery(...)[0].offset is not a function, the code what it looks like at the minute is jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('.footer-container')[0].offset().top }, 'slow'); <-- this doesn't work. But this does, document.getElementsByClassName('footer-container')[0].scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"});